# Windows Text Search Tool Including PDFs

Tags: windows, filesystems, search

Looking for recommendations for tool/process to search through roughly 2TBs of data looking for certain phrases. This would include office docs, .txt, and PDFs.

I see a lot of tools out there for this, but not seeing many that can do PDFs.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: http://www.microsoft.com/enterprisesearch/en/us/search-server-express.aspx

"The following connectors come out of the box in Search Server 2010 Express and SharePoint Server 2010:

- SharePoint sites
- Windows file shares
- Exchange public folders
- Lotus Notes
- Web sites
- IFilters for additional repositories
- Structured content in databases
- Federation object model

" - http://www.microsoft.com/enterprisesearch/searchserverexpress/en/us/compare.aspx

[PDF and other iFilters are available](http://docs.composite.net/C1/Packages/CompositeC1searchpackages/CompositeSearchMicrosoftSearchServer/Indexing-Pdf-Docx-Other-File-Types.aspx#pdf2010).

[Read this as well](http://www.donationcoder.com/forum/index.php?PHPSESSID=bjkn2r32i75luildslkpq64032&topic=26600.msg247428#msg247428) which discusses some limitations.